# Laragon, laravel. my virtual host cannot work on my PC

Tags: laravel, laragon

Anyone can helme? i get problem whit virtual host
[This is my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gzbh.png)

Comment: please describe your problem in plain English, and avoid posting screenshots as much as possible.

Comment: You should share file host and vhost you config

Comment: Please refer to https://laragon.org/docs/pretty-urls.html. Hopefully, it will resolve our query.

Answer (score 9):

I solved that issue as follow

1. **Menu -> Apache -> sites-enabled -> delete all  (auto)**
2. **C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts**   right click -> properties on **hosts** file and uncheck the **"Read-only"**
3. make sure **auto virtual host** is checked on laragon
4. restart laragon and try **your project folder name inside in **www** with .test** (or as specified in laragon setting) in the browser

Answer (score 1):

This question has entirely insufficient details to help you in any meaningful way. However, if I had to guess, I would say there are couple of possible reasons:

1. Your DNS for is not configured properly for online-shop.dev. Note, .dev is an actual top-level domain, owned by Google and reserved for their own use - https://icannwiki.org/.dev, so it's likely you are trying to follow some advice how to setup .dev for local development, but Firefox is actually looking against the real .dev DNS servers.
2. Assuming your DNS is indeed properly configured (in which case you happen to work for Google, and you just accidentally leaked their Amazon competitor :-)), it is possible that your app server is not running. It's impossible to say by the screenshot.
3. Assuming that the DNS and the app server are configured and running properly, it's possible your firewall is blocking port 80.